# Force wxWidgets 2.x with CMake

Tags: cmake, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm compiling a Code::Blocks plugin. Due to incompatibilites with wxWidgets 3.0, Code::Blocks is compiled against wxWidgets 2.8.

The CMakeLists.txt for the plugin is:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(cbvike)

SET(VERSION_SERIES 0)
SET(VERSION_MAJOR 2)
SET(VERSION_MINOR 1)

FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/include/codeblocks)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/include/codeblocks/wxscintilla/include)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D __WXGTK__)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D __linux__)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)
```

This find wxgtk 3.0 which causes some problems. I'm using Arch, so I can't only remove the development package for wxgtk 3.0 - the headers are already bundled.

How can I force wxgtk 2.x in CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I once try to make a compatible 2.x/3.x wxWidgets series...I never found out if it worked...so tell me if this work as expected:

```
# Look for wxwidgets
list (APPEND _COMP adv core base)
if (UNIX)
    set (TOOLKIT_VERSION_NEED "3.0") # change here to desired version
    set (wxWidgets_CONFIG_OPTIONS --version=${TOOLKIT_VERSION_NEED})
endif ()
find_package (wxWidgets COMPONENTS ${_COMP})
if (wxWidgets_FOUND)
    include (${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
endif ()
```

Comment: It's enough to do `set (TOOLKIT_VERSION_NEED "2.8")`
`set (wxWidgets_CONFIG_OPTIONS --version=${TOOLKIT_VERSION_NEED})` Thanks!

Comment: And it works even if we change the name `TOOLKIT_VERSION_NEED`

Comment: Well, that variable is made by me...but I mean do you have a mixed wx 2.x/3.x series installed?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Arch with both `wxgtk` and `wxgtk2.8` in here.